# What is (sqrt(1+8*long(num)) - 1)/2?

Tags: math, dynamic-programming

Hi I was looking up solutions to a leetcode problem, I know how to solve the problem but someone else submitted this solution and I don't understand how this works.

The question is how many number of stacks can you form with n number of coins where k-th row has k number of coins. https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/july-leetcoding-challenge/544/week-1-july-1st-july-7th/3377/

Returning the above formula works, can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The sum of the first N natural numbers (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N) is known to be equal to N(N+1)2
- The game says that if you have 6 coins you have to stack them in this way:

  ```
        x              (1)

        x    x         (2)

        x    x     x   (3)
  ```

  and 6 is equal to 1 + 2 + 3.
  If you are given K coins and you know that N(N+1)/2 = K then you know that you can have N rows. Now the question is, given K, how can you find N?

Let's do the math:

- N(N+1)/2 = K
- N^2 + N = 2*K
- N^2 + N -2*K = 0
- N = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8K))/2
- N = -1/2 + sqrt(1/4 + 2K)
- N = sqrt(2*K + 0.25) - 0.5

Comment: Thank you! I understand now